# How to solve php 302 error during redirect external url

Tags: php

I have used cURL for redirect my shortened url for my work, but it gives 302 http server error, how can I fix it?

```
<?php
    function openURL($url) {

      // Create a new cURL resource
      $ch = curl_init();

      // Set the file URL to fetch through cURL
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

      // Do not check the SSL certificates
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

      // Return the actual result of the curl result instead of success code
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['clickHere'])) {
        echo openURL('https://link.short2url.in/yL9E');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <button name="clickHere">Click Here To Open External URL in PHP</button>        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 302 isn't an error.

Comment: @RoToRa Then help me to access into 302-HTTP request

Comment: 302 is a temporary redirect status code.  And you are redirecting.  It's not really an error.